# Npx Create React App giving out errors and ending without install

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am getting errors whilst using the create-react-app. I am using Ubuntu, VSCode, npm. I tried clearing cache but the error still persists.

The errors are as follows:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: eslint@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@4.27.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!   @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^4.5.0" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/yourdir/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/yourdir/.npm/_logs/2021-06-15T23_17_30_641Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try digging into home/yourdir/.npm/_logs/2021-06-15T23_17_30_641Z- file

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to an issue with CRA.
https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2128
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9995

At least it sounds similar. I'm currently experiencing this issue myself and have come across these.